# Proving the Derivative of $f'(x) = b^x$

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

Given $f(x) = b^x = e^{x\ln b}$ for $b > 0$, can someone show me how $f'(x) = \ln b e^{x\ln b}$ ?

Comment: Use the chain rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said:
$$f(x)=b^x\\\ln f(x)=x\ln b \\f(x)=e^{x\ln b}$$

Now:

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^u=e^u \frac{du}{dx}$$

Hence:

$$u=x\ln b \\ \frac{du}{dx}=\ln b$$

So:

$$f'(x)=e^u \frac{du}{dx}=e^{x\ln b}\ln b$$

Comment: Thank you! Taking the derivative of x ln b, I would have tried to use the Product Rule. What am I missing?

Comment: Never mind. Got it. I was missing the obvious: $ln b$ is an actual quantity, not a variable or function.

Comment: @LMiz Yes, $\ln b$ is a constant. I was almost thrown off as well :|.

Answer (score 3):

The definition for the derivative of a real valued function $f$ is
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$

Letting $f(x) = e^{x \ln b }$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{df}{dx}&=&\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{(x+h) \ln b }-e^{x \ln b }}{h}\\
&=& \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{x \ln b }(e^{h\ln b}-1)}{h}\\
& = & e^{x \ln b }\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{b^{h}-1}{h} \\
& = &e^{x \ln b }\ln b.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: A bit overkill, resorting to first principles, but nonetheless correct. +1

Comment: Moving from that limit to ln b won't be obvious for new students.

Comment: @LMiz: In my opinion, it isn't obvious. For those interested, I like this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/374230/78492

Answer (score 2):

$$f'(x) = b^xln(b)$$
$$f'(x) = e^{ln(b)x}ln(b)$$

Answer (score 1):

$(e^u)'=u'e^u$. Then, if you set $u(x)= x\ln b$, we have $u'(x)=\ln b$. If you apply the formula, you arrive at $$\ln be^{x\ln b}$$