# Limit of $\frac{\pi^h-1}{h}$ as h approaches zero

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone help me find this limit here. I only know how to use L'Hospital's rule but I want to be able to evaluate this limit without using differentiation.
$$\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\pi^h-1}{h}$$

The reason I want this limit is because just like $e$ can be expressed as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$ I want to find a way to do the same with $\pi$ so i want to find the dervivative of $\pi^x$ without having $\pi$ in the result.

Comment: There is no way to avoid derivatives with this. The limit is $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\pi^h - \pi^0}{h-0}$, which is a difference quotient.

Comment: If you are allowed to use the fact that $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\mathrm{e}^h -1}{h}=1$, the you may use the substitution $t = h\log \pi$ to compute your limit.

Comment: @GFauxPas However, $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^h-1}{h-0}$ is also a difference quotient, but it can be calculated without derivatives.

Comment: Do you allow expanding into Taylor series? Because expanding $\pi^h = e^{h \ln \pi}$ gives this answer easily.

Comment: @SteamyRoot That's still derivatives.

Comment: Related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491220/show-lim-limits-h-to-0-fracah-1h-exists-without-lh%C3%B4pital-or-even-r

Comment: That one may be still closer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331153/proving-that-lim-h-to-0-fracbh-1h-lnb I think it  could be a duplicate;

Comment: In your latest edit you added a reason that you want this limit. However, you are not going to learn anything about $\pi$ by this method. Why not? Because there is a completely general formula: $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} = \ln(a)$. Whatever method you find for proving this formula in the special case $a=\pi$ will work for any $a>0$.

Comment: @LeeMosher So really I'm looking for a way to express the natural log of a number rationally. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "express ... rationally".

Answer (score 1):

There's no way we can avoid $\pi$ here. The value of this limit is $\log\pi$. Despite the method we use to get that limit, the exact value is $\log\pi$ and there's no way to avoid that. We can, however, do this without limits.

---

Let's say $\pi=e^{\ln \pi}$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{h\ln\pi}-1}{h}$$
Now, we take [@SangchiLee's advice](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9340/sangchul-lee) and say $t=h\log \pi$, so that $h=\frac{t}{\log \pi}$:
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{e^t-1}{\frac{t}{\log \pi}}$$
Simplify:
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \log\pi\frac{e^t-1}{t}$$
Take the $\log\pi$ out of the limit:
$$\log\pi\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{e^t-1}{t}$$
Now, [the limit on the right is equal to $1$](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/evaluating-limit-as-h-0-of-e-h-1-h.623092/), so we have:
$$\log\pi\cdot 1=\log\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{hln\pi}-1}{h} = (H) = $$
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ln{\pi} * lne^{hln\pi}}{1} = ln \pi $$

Answer (score -1):

You don't need that limit to compute the derivative of $a^x$ though.  ($a$ a constant)

Since $a = e^{ \ln a}$ (log and exponential are inverse functions), you have $a^x = e^{(\ln a )x}$, so $$ \frac{d}{dx}(a^x) = \frac{d}{dx} e^{(\ln a)x} = (\ln a) e^{(\ln a) x}$$

Comment: That's still circular in the way as OP wants to avoid it.

Comment: @5xum see the current version of the post.