# Limit as $x$ goes to $2$ of $\dfrac{2^x - x^2}{x-2}$

Tags: limits

> $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 2}\dfrac{2^x - x^2}{x-2}$

Comment: I edited it, but also voted for closing as “missing context”. Do you know the definition of derivative? Another hint: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to2}\left(\frac{2^x-4}{x-2}-\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}\right)$

Comment: Yeah but the problem should be solved without using it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x-2=h$

$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{2^{h+2}-(h+2)^2}h=2^2\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{2^h-1}h-\lim_{h\to0}(h+2)$$

Now for $a>0, a=e^{\ln a}$

$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{a^h-1}h=\ln a\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{e^{h\ln a}-1}{h\ln a}=\ln a$$

Comment: Could you explain the last eqatuion its 0/0

Comment: @user379685, Do you mean http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152605/proving-that-lim-limits-x-to-0-fracex-1x-1  ?

Comment: That's not it or at least i dont see the connection

Comment: @user379685, Please write the line causing your confusion ?

Comment: (a^h - 1)/h = ln a

Comment: @user379685, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331153/proving-that-lim-h-to-0-fracbh-1h-lnb   OR http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491220/show-lim-limits-h-to-0-fracah-1h-exists-without-lh%C3%B4pital-or-even-r

Answer (score 1):

Herein, we present a way forward that does not use differential calculus, but rather relies only on a standard set of inequalities and the squeeze theorem.  To that end, we begin with a primer.

> **PRIMER:**
>
> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the exponential function satisfies the inequalities
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{1+x\le e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x}} \tag 1$$
>
> for $x<1$.

---

Next, we note that we can write $2^x=4e^{\log(2)(x-2)}$.  Thne, using $(2)$ reveals that

$$4(1+\log(2)(x-2)) \le2^x\le \frac{4}{1-\log(2)(x-2)}$$

for $x<2+1/\log(2)$.

Therefore, we can write for $2<x<2+1/\log(2)$

$$4\log(2)-(x+2) \le \frac{2^x-x^2}{x-2}\le \frac{\log(2)x^2 -(x+2)}{1-\log(2)(x-2)} \tag 2$$

while for $x<2$ we can write

$$ \frac{\log(2)x^2 -(x+2)}{1-\log(2)(x-2)} \le \frac{2^x-x^2}{x-2}\le 4\log(2)-(x+2) \tag 3$$

> Applying the squeeze theorem to $(2)$ and $(3)$ yields the coveted limit
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{2^x-x^2}{x-2}=4\log(2)-4}$$